Why am I getting 401 error even though I have access to Twitter API?
I'm currently doing my bachelor thesis and I wanted to use twitter to do a sentiment analysis, which is why I am trying to teach myself python.
I'm trying to pull tweets, but I keep getting the 401 error. According to my developer dashboard I should have access.
    401
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-dd05c5c7c0b7> in <cell line: 38>()
         37 
         38 if __name__ == "__main__":
    ---> 39     main()

    1 frames
    <ipython-input-2-dd05c5c7c0b7> in connect_to_endpoint(url, params)
         27     print(response.status_code)
         28     if response.status_code != 200:
    ---> 29         raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
         30     return response.json()
         31 

    Exception: (401, '{\n  "title": "Unauthorized",\n  "type": "about:blank",\n  "status":    401,\n  "detail": "Unauthorized"\n}')

I've tried different codes, all of which return the same error. The codes are mostly what I found online, for example the Twitter-API-v2 sample code on GitHub. I've tried authentication with just the bearer code (app only authentication) and OAuth 1.0a. I've regenerated my all of my tokens. I changed the settings in the dashboard to read and write (maybe it takes a little to adjust the access?). The dashboard says I have V2 access and limited V1.1 access.
I come from a humanities background and this is basically my first time trying to code.

"I'm trying to pull tweets, but I keep getting the 401 error." Pulling tweets requires one of the paid for access tiers: Basic ($100/month) for searching from the last 7 days or Pro ($5000/month) for historical searches.
